# Cannot set up Google App Engine for Python 2.7 on OSX 10.6

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, python-2.5

Trying to run the Python 2.7 dev environment for Google App Engine on Mac OSX (10.6.8), but I cannot get the helloworld example won't run.

I cannot import webapp2 in a Python shell.  When I try to run from the GUI, the log reports that my "Python command" is /usr/bin/python2.6, though my system default is 2.7.  When I try to visit localhost:8080 I get "ImportError: No module named urllib".

Tried launching from the command line with /usr/local/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py helloworld/.  Got error:

```
fancy_urllib.InvalidCertificateException: Host appengine.google.com returned an invalid certificate (_ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed): 
To learn more, see http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#rpcssl.
```

Thinking the application might be using 2.5, and per the "learn more" link, I installed ssl to Python2.5 (downloaded code, << sudo python2.5 setup.py install >>).  While I could now import ssl into a Python 2.5 shell, I still got the same error when running the dev server.

I did do my own install of Python 2.7 on this computer, so it is possible that in doing so I broke / missed something subtle.

Also, the software README refers only to 2.5, and has a latest date of April 2008.  I see only one Python download at the [downloads page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `python -V` report?

Comment: did you get any resolution on this?

Comment: I did get the command line working.  I have notes on how.  If you are in a hurry, comment and I'll try to lift a fuller explanation to top of queue.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be able to `import webapp2` in Python shell since webapp2 is not in the default packages.

Make sure that you have the latest Launcher for MacOS running on your computer and try the following:

- Run the **GoogleAppEngineLauncher**
- **File** > **New Application...**
- Choose a name and press **Create**
- Press **Run**
- Press **Browse**

If following the above steps you will see the **Hello, world!** in the browser then you are good to continue with your Hello, world! application.

If not make sure that you're running the `dev_appserver.py` from a command line by using the correct version of Python, or if you're running using the Launcher in the **preferences** you might need to add the **Python Path** to point to the `python2.7`.